# Varias funcoes em uma so

Tags: javascript

Tenho duas funções independentes que aplicam formatação em planilha do googledocs, e gostaria de junta-las em uma só. São as funções 1 e 2 abaixo.

FUNÇÃO 1

```
function nomeColunas() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var nomes = [["DATA", "AUDITOR", "MEDIDAS SOLICITADAS",]];

  var faixa = sheet.getRange("A1:I1");
  faixa.setValues(nomes);
}
```

FUNÇÃO 2

```
function formataCelulas() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var faixa = sheet.getRangeList(['A:M']);

  faixa.setHorizontalAlignment('center');
  faixa.setVerticalAlignment('middle');
  faixa.setWrap(true);
  Logger.log(formataCelulas);

}
```

Comment: Não depende de nada não. É exatamente o que o colega respondeu, que funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá! Seria algo assim:

```
function formataPlanilha() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var nomes = [["DATA", "AUDITOR", "MEDIDAS SOLICITADAS",]];
    var faixaColNome = sheet.getRange("A1:I1"); // Nome Colunas
    var faixaCelula = sheet.getRangeList(['A:M']); // Formata Celulas

    // Nome Colunas
    faixaColNome.setValues(nomes);

    // Formata Celulas
    faixaCelula.setHorizontalAlignment('center');
    faixaCelula.setVerticalAlignment('middle');
    faixaCelula.setWrap(true);
    Logger.log(formataPlanilha);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado em algo :)